# How do I display an object's class type, and create a sorted, comma separated list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, repr

My problem states:

Create a class, called DataManager, that is used to keep track of simple statistics associated with a set of files.  Each file is expected to contain tab-separated lines of similar data.  Implement the methods below for full credit.

**init**: The DataManager constructor accepts no parameters other than self.  The constructor creates the following attributes:
      #1) a dictionary attribute, called data, to store the data (the dictionary maps index integers to lists of values).
      #2) an integer attribute, called recordnum, to store the current index value (should always be the index of the next record to add).
      #3) a list attribute, called file_list, to store the file or files that will be added.

**repr**: Displays the type of object (DataManager) and a comma separated list of the files that have been added to the object.  This list of file names must be sorted.

I keep getting either a TypeError or an AttributeError for my **repr** method. How do I correct this?

My current code:

```
  #Method: __init__
    #Data is a dictionary, recordnum is an integer, 
    #file_list is a list to store added file(s). 
    #Self, Dict, Int, List -> Self
    def __init__ (self):

        self.data = {}
        self.file_list = []
        self.recordnum = 0


    #Method: __repr__
    def __repr__ (self): 

         return type(object)
         return str(sorted(self.file_list.split(','))
```

Comment: "Displays" is not the same as "returns".

Comment: I'm relatively new to coding. Would displaying just be printing?

Comment: Typically, but I'd check w/ whomever wrote the assignment.

Comment: 1) In `__repr__` you have two returns.  Only the first one will be executed but should be type(self).  2) `file_list` is a list not a string.  To get a comma separated list you want `','.join(sorted(self.file_list))`.  3)  Putting 1 & 2 together you want: `return f'{type(self)}: ','.join(sorted(self.file_list))'`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a repper returns a precise string representation of the object that allows you to recreate it with `eval`:

`eval(repr(instance)) --> instance`

in your case, that could be something like this:

```
class MyQuestion:

    def __init__ (self, file_list):
        self.data = {}
        self.file_list = file_list[:]
        self.recordnum = 0

    def __repr__ (self): 
         return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({sorted(self.file_list)})'

MyQuestion([2, 4, 6, 1, 3])

# ---> 'MyQuestion([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])'
```